# Selecting image does not return to my app

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I'm accessing the gallery and camera via a seperate intent using the following code:

```
final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Now in the gallery when I select an image it returns to my home screen. When I hit back, I also return to my home screen. Same with the camera when hitting back or capture I return to the home screen. I want it to return to my previous activity after doing activities on my gallery or camera. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Given code is insufficient for detecting the problem. How did you call this Activity? Also, give different 'requestCode' for these 2 calls.

Comment: I call these codes at a btn click. That's the only code I use to open up the gallery and camera.

Comment: kindly show your `@overrided startActivityForResult` method and tell us more specific that what really you want?

Comment: 2 possibilities are there. **1.** your activity is not present in activity-stack. Thats why I asked you to show the code that calls current activity(not gallery). **2.** you did something inside `onActivityResult()` that navigate to home activity. Thats why ZubairAhmadKhan asked you so.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for getting a picture from the gallery. Control returns back to the app.

```
    Intent gallery_intent = new Intent();
    gallery_intent.setType("*/*");
    gallery_intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery_intent, ""), CHOOSE_PICTURE);
    Intent camera_intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAPTURE_PICTURE);
```

Make sure you have included camera permission in the Manifest. CHOOSE_PICTURE and CAPTURE_PICTURE are two contants.

Comment: Does this allow multiple selections on gallery?